# How to check how my process in linux centos gets killed?

Tags: centos

I am quite new to linux administration. My question is, is there any way to check log files or any files how my process gets TERM signal or get killed. Can we know who killed the running process as an admin? Might be because of another admin for some system updates?

Answer (score 2):

You could use auditing to audit the systemcall for kill. Edit the file /etc/audit/audit.rules (EL6) (or /etc/audit/rules.d/audit.rules(EL7)) and add something like

```
-a entry,always -F arch=b64 -S kill -k catch_kill
```

restart auditd

```
service auditd restart
```

Note: you need to do the for [EL7 to restart auditd](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1026648) too.

Now you can search the audit log for entries tagged `catch_kills`

```
ausearch -k catch_kills
```

and get an entry like this which will probably tell you what you want to know.

> time->Sun Sep  4 19:05:54 2016
>   type=OBJ_PID msg=audit(1473012354.105:6138): opid=3151 oauid=1000 ouid=0 oses=619 obj=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 ocomm="sleep"
>   type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1473012354.105:6138): arch=c000003e syscall=62 success=yes exit=0 a0=c4f a1=f a2=0 a3=7ffd235ac0d0 items=0 ppid=3046 pid=3050 auid=1000 uid=0 gid=0 euid=0 suid=0 fsuid=0 egid=0 sgid=0 fsgid=0 tty=pts0 ses=619 comm="bash" exe="/usr/bin/bash" subj=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 key="catch_kills"

There is extensive documentation on the EL audit system on the [Red Hat website](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Security_Guide/chap-system_auditing.html)

Comment: It would be great if I could know how only one specific user's process are getting killed at random time. I am pretty sure all the process of user "X" are getting killed intentionally at random times. Would be great if the cause can be found. Looked at audit log files. But could be get any information.

Comment: It would be great if you went ad read the documentation and educated yourself. Hint: _you_ have to configure the audit daemon to log what _you_ want. didn't you even read my answer ?

Comment: I wouldn't ask you the same question if it had worked. Unfortunately it didn't. Again the process get killed by SIGTERM. I went through the documentation as you posted, but didn't helped in my case.